# Mysql select Query with multiple conditions of same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, in-operator

I need MySQL select query like

```
select wt_id,wt_name from work_type where cat_id=1,2,5..;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I got the desired result using 'IN' operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use [**IN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator

```
SELECT wt_id, wt_name 
FROM work_type 
WHERE cat_id IN (1,2,5..);
```

Comment: This result works as ORed query.. What about ANDed queries? Can u refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567903/mysql-select-query-anded-multiple-condition-of-same-column)

Answer (score 3):

Use IN operator ex.

```
... where cat_id IN (1,2,5..)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL IN operator.

SELECT wt_id, wt_name 
FROM work_type 
WHERE cat_id IN (1,2,5..);

If you have any question please comment below.